# Does drinking milk and orange juice together cause digestion problems?

Tags: nutrition, milk, drinks

I was once having a milky coffee at a cafe and I ordered an orange juice.
The waiter told me that I should wait until I've finished my coffee, because drinking milk and orange juice together causes the milk to curdle inside your stomach.

- Is there any evidence of digestion or other problems being caused by drinking orange juice with milk?

Answer (score 14):

As seen in [this experiment](http://scienceblogs.com/ethicsandscience/2008/05/friday_sprog_blogging_experime.php) **milk curdles when lemon juice is added** (due to the acid):

[image]

> [Orange juice has a pH level of about
>   3](http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/Chem_AcidsBasespHScale.shtml)

so that could curdle the milk.

**But**

> [gastric acid has a pH level of 1.5 -
>   3](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003883.htm)

---

**Conclusion**:

Due to the gastric acid milk would curdle in your stomach anyway.

Comment: Note: milk + lemon = ricotta cheese + milk serum ;-)

Comment: Of course, it's entirely possible for there to be digestion problems due to something else...

Comment: Both milk and OJ give a lot of people many digestive problems. I'm gonna go with a false causation conclusion, where there is probably at best a weak correlation.