# Does drinking milk tea after drinking lemon tea make you sick?

Tags: nutrition, milk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does drinking milk and orange juice together cause digestion problems?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/does-drinking-milk-and-orange-juice-together-cause-digestion-problems)

Someone told me not to drinking milk tea after drinking lemon tea, or the reverse. He told me the milk and the lemon juice will conglomerate together.

And I heard one of my friend was sick several month ago and she thought it was probably the milk tea and the lemon juice she drinked. And last on she visited a doctor, and the doctor told her that was probably the reason.

True?

Comment: Yes, it is a fact that lemon juice will curdle milk. It is a reaction with the acid in the lemon juice. Curdling of milk with an acid is the first step in cheesemaking. Curdling of milk also occurs immediately after you drink it, because your stomach contains a strong acid. So, generally speaking, curdled milk is perfectly healthy. Can you most kindly explain what specifically about the mixture of milk and lemon juice is supposed to be unhealthy? Did the doctor explain this?

Comment: The duplicate is about orange juice, but the principle behind it is the same.

Comment: Ever drank a nice cup of Earl Grey with a dash of milk?

Comment: What a terrible doctor...